# Find nested repeater in 3 level repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a 3-level asp.net repeater, and I need to find the 3rd level's items. The code-behind is posted below as well.

Here is my aspx code:

```
<div class="container">
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptGrp0" OnItemDataBound="rptGrp0_ItemDataBound">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <div id="Grp0" class="rptParent">
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="rptParent <%# Eval("Name") %>">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span12">
                            <h5 class="parentTitle"><%# Eval("Name") %></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="group">
                    <div id="rptChild <%# Eval("Name") %>">
                        <div>
                            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptGrp1" OnItemDataBound="rptGrp1_ItemDataBound">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <div id="Grp1" class="rptChild">
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div class="group">
                                        <div id="rptGrandChildHeader <%# Eval("Name") %>">
                                            <div class="content">
                                                <div class="container">
                                                    <div class="row-fluid">
                                                        <div class="span12">
                                                            <p class="blue">
                                                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblChildName" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="rptGrandChild <%# Eval("Name") %>">
                                            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptContent">
                                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                                    <div class="c_module">
                                                        <div class="container">
                                                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                                                <div class="span12">
                                                                    <div class="data_controls">
                                                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="d_table_module">
                                                                        <table border="0" class="display" id="tblContent">
                                                                            <thead>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <th>Product</th>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                            </thead>
                                                                            <tbody>
                                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="width:100px;">
                                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblProduct" Text='<%# Eval("Product") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                                            </tbody>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:Repeater>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                </div>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </div>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
```

Here is my code-behind.

```
protected void lnkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Repeater primary = (Repeater)this.FindControl("rptGrp0");
    if (primary != null)
    {
        // Items.Count = 0.
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in primary.Items)
        {
            Repeater secondary = (Repeater)item.FindControl("rptGrp1");
            if (secondary != null)
            {
                foreach (RepeaterItem b in secondary.Items)
                {
                    Repeater target = (Repeater)b.FindControl("rptContent");
                    if (target != null)
                    {
                        foreach (RepeaterItem c in target.Items)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that my repeater.Items.Count is 0.

Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution. It has to do with the ASP.NET page lifecycle.

After the lnkButton_Click event, a postback occurred, but I needed to "rebind" the repeater datasource on postback, not just initial page_load.

e.g.

```
protected void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // bind control
    }
    else
    {
        // rebind control
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Repeater` will display only if it is bounded with `DataSource`. Make sure your repeaters are bounded with a proper `DataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the items of the 3rd repeater depends on how you databind it to begin with.  If you are binding data in your `Page_Load` event, then the data is bound **after** the click event is processed.  On your `lnkButton_Click` event the contents of the repeaters have not yet been bound.  The easiest way to access those items is to have an `Item_DataBound` event to access those items.

Sample code:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptContent" OnItemDataBound="rptContent_ItemDataBound">
...
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void rptContent_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.Item; // This current item

    Repeater rpt = (Repeater)(sender);
    rpt.Items; // All items

    //Do some condition here to test on the item for whatever you want to do
    if(e.Item == someCondition)
        // some operation here
}
```